# Upload video from S3 to YouTube via Data API without downloading file

Tags: boto3, youtube-data-api, youtube-api

I'm incorporating the YouTube Data API into a Django application, and I'm attempting to upload a video that I store in AWS S3 to YouTube without having to download a file or keep the video on the local filesystem. The YouTube API docs state that the syntax for uploading a video is:

```
insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )
```

The media_body parameter here is the actual upload. The MediaFileUpload here takes as an argument a path to a local file. However, I can't figure out how the youtube.videos().insert() method uses this argument because the **youtube** object's methods here are constructed rather convolutedly using googleapiclient.discovery.build [with the Google API Client code here on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery.py) and the [YouTube API docs don't cover it that well](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video). Does anyone know if it's possible to use a stream of an S3 video using boto3 or something else to upload a video from S3 directly to YouTube via the API without having to download it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi xander, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hey @Josir I unfortunately didn't find any solution for this. I still have to keep the file locally to be able to use it in the YouTube API.